# prediction interval for arma-garch models in python

Tags: python, intervals, arch

Is there a way to measure the accuracy of an ARMA-GARCH model in Python using a prediction interval (alpha=0.05)? I fitted an ARMA-GARCH model on log returns and used some classical metrics such as RMSE, MSE (out-of-sample), AIC (in-sample), check on residuals and so on. I would like to add a prediction interval as another measurement of accuracy based on my ARMA-GARCH model predictions. I used the armagarch library (https://github.com/iankhr/armagarch).
I already checked on how to use prediction intervals but not sure how to use it with ARMA-GARCH.
I found these formula searching online: Estimator +- 1.96 (for 95%) * Standard Error.
So far i got it, but i have several Standard Errors in my model output for each parameter in the ARMA and GARCH part, which one i have to use? Is there one Standard Error for the whole model itself?

I would be really happy if anyone could help.

[ARMA-GARCH model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNBpM.png)

So far I created an ARMA(2,2)-GARCH(1,1) model:

```
#final test of function

import armagarch as ag

#definitions framework
data = pd.DataFrame(data)


meanMdl = ag.ARMA(order = {'AR':2,'MA':2})
volMdl = ag.garch(order = {'p':1,'q':1})
distMdl = ag.normalDist()
model = ag.empModel(data, meanMdl, volMdl, distMdl)
model_fit = model.fit()
```

After the model fit defining prediction length and
Recieved  two arrays as an output (mean + variance) put them into the correct length:

```
    #first array is mean, second is variance
pred = model.predict(nsteps=len(df_test))

#correct the shapes!
df_pred_mean = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(pred[0], (len(df_test), 
1)))
df_pred_variance = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(pred[1], 
(len(df_test), 1)))
```

So far so good, now i would like to implement a prediction interval.
I got that one has to use the ARMA part +- 1.96 (95%)* GARCH prediction for each prediction. I implemented it for the upper and lower bound. It just shows the upper bound lower bound is same but using * (-1.96) at the end of the formula.

```
#upper bound 
df_all["upper bound"] =df_all["pred_Mean"]+df_all["pred_Variance"]*1.96
```

Using it on the actual log returns i trained the model with fails in the way its completely wrong. Now I'm unsure if the main approach i used is wrong or the model I used means the package.

[prediction interval vs. actual log return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHM6X.png)

Comment: It would help if you included your actual code in the question, that way it's easier for others to reproduce and work with your problem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and have a nice day

Comment: @ The Lemon I changed the main issue and added some code. Is it fine that way? I use this forum for the very first time, so I try my best.

Comment: looks great, unfortunately I know nothing about the topic haha, you'll have to wait and see if anyone vibes with the question